# Parsing of optionals with PEG (Grako) falling short?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ebnf, peg, grako

My colleague PaulS asked me the following:

---

I'm writing a parser for an existing language (SystemVerilog - an IEEE standard), and the specification has a rule in it that is similar in structure to this:

```
cover_point 
    = 
    [[data_type] identifier ':' ] 'coverpoint' identifier ';' 
    ;

data_type 
    = 
    'int' | 'float' | identifier 
    ;

identifier 
    = 
    ?/\w+/? 
    ;
```

The problem is that when parsing the following legal string:

```
anIdentifier: coverpoint another_identifier;
```

`anIdentifier` matches with `data_type` (via its identifier option) successfully, which means Grako is looking for another identifier after it and then fails. It doesn't then try to parse without the data_type part.

I can re-write the rule as follows,

```
cover_point_rewrite  
    = 
    [data_type identifier ':' | identifier ':' ] 'coverpoint' identifier ';' 
    ;
```

but I wonder if:

1. this is intentional and
2. if there's a better syntax?

---

Is this a PEG-in-general issue, or a tool (Grako) one?

Comment: My own take on it is that, yeah, one must tweak grammars to force PEG parsers to choose the longest possible option first.

Answer (score 2):

It says [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) that in PEGs the choice operator is *ordered* to avoid CFGs ambiguities by using the first match.

In your first example

```
[data_type]
```

succeeds parsing id, so it fails when it finds `:` instead of another identifier.
That may be because `[data_type]` behaves like `(data_type | ε)` so it will always parse `data_type` with the first id.

In

```
[data_type identifier ':' | identifier ':' ]
```

the first choice fails when there is no second id, so the parser backtracks and tries with the second choice.